# "# questions with new activity" banner. Inconsistent; seems like a bug

Tags: bug, android-app

I was on the app, and again, I saw a banner accross the top with a refresh button:

[image: New activity screenshot]

The weird things are:

- I had only been on this page for a second. It's seems extraordinarily unlikely within that second, 5 posts had new activity.
- The refresh button on the right doesn't do anything. I clicked it, held it, prayed, nothing happened.
- I don't recall having updated the app recently, and this is only the third time I've ever seen this in like 4 years of using the app. Y'all thought I was crazy the first two times because I didn't have a screenshot. But here it is! I use this app daily, and it seems odd that it just seems to randomly pop up, and *only ever on the Meta sites*.

Is this a partially implemented feature that wasn't fully disabled or something?

```
App version: 1.0.95
Android 8.0.0 (Note 8)
```